# What is the difference between derefencing and assigning the address of a variable to pointer variable in C?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, memory-address, dereference

See the two codes below!

```
int main() {
    int a = 12;
    int *p;
    *p = a;
}
```

and the this code,

```
int main() {
    int a = 12;
    int *p;
    p = &a;
}
```

In the first piece of code dereferenced the pointer as this `*p = a`, and in the second piece of code, the address of variabe `a` is set to the pointer variable.

My question is what is the difference between both pieces of codes?

Comment: Well, the first is UB because p is undefined when you dereference it:(

Comment: A pointer must ALWAYS point to valid memory. Ask yourself *"Where does `p` point (e.g. what valid address does `p` hold as its value) in your first example?"* In your second example, you assign the *address of* `a` to `p` -- so now `p` holds the address of `a` as its value (e.g. `p` points to `a`). Remember, a pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the address of something else as its value.

Comment: The first is like delivering a package to a house that does not exist, the second is like writing down the address of your friend's house.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler give you a hint? No "making pointer from integer" warning?

Comment: No warnings, it just compiled with no warnings :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first piece of code:

```c
int main() {
    int a = 12;
    int *p;
    *p = a;
}
```

you have a serious case of **undefined behaviour** because, what you are trying to do is assign the value of `a` to the `int` variable that `p` **currently** points to. However, `p` has not been assigned an 'address', so it will have an arbitrary  - and ***invalid*** - value! *Some* compilers may initialise `p` to zero (or `NULL`) but that is still an invalid address (on *most* systems).

Your second code snippet is 'sound' but, as it stands, doesn't *actually* achieve anything:

```c
int main() {
    int a = 12;
    int *p;
    p = &a;
}
```

Here, you are assigning a value (i.e. an **address**) to your pointer variable, `p`; in this case, `p` now *points to* the `a` variable (that is, it's value is the *address* of `a`).

So, if you appended code like this (to the end of your second snippet):

```c
*p = 42;
```

and then printed out the value of `a`, you would see that its value has been changed from the initially-given `12` to `42`.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: In my compiler(clang), in the first case, if I print say (`printf("The address is %p\n", p)`) it prints an address. what going on there?

Comment: As I said in my answer, the 'address' printed will be an *arbitrary* (sort of random) value. It may well print a different 'address' each time you run the code. But that is ***not*** a valid address (i.e. it doesn't *point* to a valid piece of memory).

Answer (score 3):

Declaring `*p` and `a` is reserving some space in memory, for a pointer in first case, for what `a` is in the 2nd case (an `int`).

In these both cases, their values are not initialized if you don't put anything in it. That doesn't mean there is *nothing* in it, as that is not possible. It means their values are undetermined, kind of "random" ; the loader just put the code/data in memory when requested, and the space occupied by `p`, and the one occupied by `a`, are both whatever the memory had at the time of loading (could be also at time of compilation, but anyway, undetermined).

So you take a big risk in doing `*p = a` in the 1<sup>st</sup> case, since you ask the processeur to take the bytes "inside" `a` and store them wherever `p` points at. Could be within the bounds of your data segments, in the stack, somewhere it won't cause an *immediate* problem/crash, but the chances are, it's *very* likely that won't be ok!

This is why this issue is said to cause "Undefined Behavior" (UB).

Answer (score 1):

The first one is bad:

```
int main() {
    int a = 12;
    int *p;
    *p = a;
}
```

It means: put the value of variable `a` into location, pointed by pointer `p`. But what the `p` points? probably nothing (NULL) or any random address. In best case, it can make execution error like access violation or segmentation fault. In worst case, it can overwrite any existing value of totally unknown variable, resulting in problems, which are very hard to investigate.

The second one is OK.

```
int main() {
    int a = 12;
    int *p;
    p = &a;
}
```

It means: get the pointer to (existing) variable `a` and assign it to pointer `p`. So, this will work OK.

Comment: "*But what the p points? nothing (NULL)*" chances are very good it just it just points somewhere different from `NULL`.

Comment: As per the C Standard only global or static variables (of **any** type, BTW)  will be implicitly initialised before their 1st usage, everything else is guessing. I won't guess.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialized a pointer you can use *p to access at the value of pointer of the pointed variable and not the address of the pointed variable but it's not possible to affect value like that (with *p=a). Because you try to affect a value without adress of variable.

The second code is right use p = &a

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between dereferencing and assigning the address of a variable to pointer variable in C?

The latter is the premise for the first. They are separate steps to achieve the benefit of pointer dereferencing.

---

For the the explanation for where the difference between those are, we have to look what these guys are separately:

---

- What is dereferencing the pointer?

First we need to look what a reference is. A reference is f.e. an identifier for an object. We could say "Variable `a` stands for the value of `12`." - thus, `a` is a reference to the value of `12`.

The identifier of an object is a reference for the value stored within.

The same goes for pointers. pointers are just like usual objects, they store a value inside, thus they *refer* to the stored values in them.

"Dereferencing" is when we "disable" this connection to the usual value within and use the identifier of `p` to access/refer to a different value than the value  stored in `p`.

"Dereferencing a pointer" means simply, you use the pointer to access the value stored in another object, f.e. `12` in `a` instead through its own identifier of `a`.

To dereference the pointer the `*` dereference operator needs to precede the pointer variable, like `*p`.

---

- What is assigning the address of a variable to a pointer?

We are achieving the things stated in "What is dereferencing a pointer?", by giving the pointer an address of another object as its value, in analogy like we assign a value to a usual variable.

But as opposed to usual object initializations/assignments, for this we need to use the `&` ampersand operator, preceding the variable, whose value the pointer shall point to and the `*` dereference operator, preceding the pointer, has to be omitted, like:

```
  p = &a;
```

Therafter, The pointer "points" to the address the desired value is stored at.

---

#### Steps to dereferencing a pointer properly:

First thing to do is to declare a pointer, like:

```
 int *p;
```

In this case, we declare a pointer variable of `p` which points to an object of type `int`.

---

Second step is to initialize the pointer with an address value of an object of type `int`:

```
 int a = 12;
 p = &a;       //Here we assign the address of `a` to p, not the value of 12.
```

Note: If you want the address value of an object, like a usual variable, you need to use the unary operator of `&`, preceding the object.

---

If you have done these steps, you are finally be able to access the value of the object the pointer points to, by using the `*`operator, preceding the pointer object:

```
     *p = a;
```

---

> My question is what is the difference between both pieces of codes?

The difference is simply as that, that the first piece of code:

```
int main() {
    int a = 12;
    int *p;
    *p = a;
}
```

is invalid for addressing an object by dereferencing a pointer. You cannot assign a value to the pointer´s dereference, if there isn´t made one reference before to which the pointer do refer to.

Thus, your assumption of:

> In the first piece of code I dereferenced the pointer as this *p = a...

is incorrect.

You do not be able to dereference the pointer at all in the proper way with `*p = a` in this case, because the pointer `p`  doesn´t has any reference, to which you are be able to dereference the pointer correctly to.

In fact, you are assigning the value of `a` with the statement of `*p = a` somewhere into the Nirwana of your memory.

Normally, the compiler *shall* never pass this through without an error.

If he does and you later want to use the value, which you think you´d assigned properly by using the pointer, like `printf("%d",*p)` you should get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.